Turning a microwave transformer into an electromagnet
So I want to turn a microwave transformer into an electromagnet. I've already harvested the transformer, cut through the welds, and removed the coils. I want to know where to position the one coil within the core, since it originally had room for two coils. See the rough sketch for the two arrangements, I'd like to know which one will maximize magnetic force.

Edit: For clarification I am planning to use one of the coils that came from the transformer. I'm also using DC current.

If you can use the existing either high voltage or mains voltage winding for your magnet, then use that, rather than winding your own. The space efficiency achieved on microwave oven transformer windings far exceeds anything you could do by hand. More conductor in there means both better electrical efficiency and better thermal conductivity.

The magnetic circuit is approximately the same either way.

"Approximate" in an interesting word here; I think the real difference will be around 20%: not huge like orders of magnitude, but maybe enough to prefer the one.

@TimWilliams Are you assuming the end will be open in use or closed with another ferromagnetic material? Coil position in a closed magnetic circuit is more like a 1% effect, IME.

Depends what it's used on. 20% would be the worser case, for an open or diamagnetic case. Or well I suppose it's even worse for a diamagnetic load. Unless you have a close fitting magnetic load (also laminated iron), I don't think the difference will be as small as 1%, those cores aren't very good, but a few percent feels right yeah.

The coil will naturally try to move up to the load. So, you will need to secure it in place somehow, preferably with something that is not magnetic. The "pro" of placing it near the open end is that it will be closer to the load, and marginally more efficient. The "con" is that if the coil is not protected, it may become damaged in use.

The coil will tend to move away from the open end actually; it will repel from a conductive object placed in the field, and attract towards the base of the core (moving towards the right-side case if not constrained).

@TimWilliams Is the OP planning on using AC or DC to drive the magnet? I was imagining DC.

If DC, then diamagnetic transiently until field settles, and it reverts to the (open or closed) case. In the special case where the load is solid magnetic and close fitted, the coil sees similar forces at either end of its travel (which yeah, would be attracted to either extreme).
